# Rails - Cannot Ajaxify Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, devise

I am trying to make Devise work purely on `AJAX` with all the requests/responses using `JSON`.

Here is my code so far:

I have started with the `Devise::RegistrationsController`:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  respond_to :json
end
```

And my corresponding view is:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">

    <h1>Sign up</h1>

    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), remote: true, format: :json, html: {id: "registration"}) do |f| %>
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <% if @validatable %>
          (<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)
        <% end %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control" %>
      </div>

      <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

    <% end %>

    <%= render "users/shared/links" %>

  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4"></div>  
</div>
```

The `AJAX` request is made successfully but I keep getting the response as `HTML`.

Here is the log entry:

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2015-05-21 21:22:10 -0700
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"email"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
   (1.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.3ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendered users/shared/_links.html.erb (2.2ms)
  Rendered users/registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (20.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 444ms (Views: 361.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change your devise.rn initalizer adding this line:

```
config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html, :json]
```

You've done right the `RegistrationsController` but you need to tell devise to use yours e not his.

Change your routes.rb to this:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: "users/registrations"}
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Are you sure about this? Have you tried it?

Comment: Okay, I've missed one step. Try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in your views.

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), remote: true, format: :json, html: {id: "registration"}) do |f| %>
```

to this.

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name, format: :json), remote: true, html: {id: "registration"}) do |f| %>
```

The Post Ajax request that you send to devise should be.

```
POST "/users.json"
```

and not

```
POST "/users"
```

Comment: Did this and now I am getting a 422 unprocessable entity error. I also noticed all my devise routes now return json so the registration form in not rendering and I am get the user object as json.